# Identify the surface whose equation in spherical coordinates $\rho\sin\phi \cos ⁡ \theta = 5$

Tags: spherical-coordinates

Shouldn't this just be a line since $x=p\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$ why is this not the case, and if it's not what shape is it?

Comment: $\phi$ is the angle from $z$ axis?

Comment: In $3$D coordinates $x = n$ describes a plane parallel to the $yz$ plane. Make sure you see why!